# How to deal with initial null values react.js

Tags: reactjs, null

I have a view. Its sample code is

```
const [a, seta] = useState(null)
useEffect(() => {
        if(!a){

            geta(match.params.id);
        }
    })
return (
a.props
);
```

But it is giving error can't read property of null value

Comment: `a?.props` i.e. [Optional Chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Why the Error?

Your code returns `a.props` before useEffect assigns `a` a value. Effectively you are returning props of null, hence the error.

> "By default, effects run after every completed render" - [React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect)

#### How to Fix

You could conditionally return the data: `return(a && a.props ? a.props : null)`

For an example in context, something like this should work:

```js
const [a, seta] = useState(null)
  useEffect(() => {
          if(!a){
              seta({greeting: 'Hello World'});
          }
      })
  return (
    a && a.greeting ? a.greeting : null
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The following code returns an error because `a` is null on the first render, prior to `useEffect` kicking in and updating `a`'s value.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const App = () => {

  const [a, seta] = useState(null)
  useEffect(() => {
    /*  ... do what you need to do */
  }, [])

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Your state:</h1>
      <h2>{a.props}</h2>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

[image: The observed error statement]

---

Instead, add a type guard in your return function to prevent a `null` value before `useEffect` fires:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const App = () => {
  const [a, seta] = useState(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    /*  ... do what you need to do */
    setTimeout(() => seta({ props: 'test'}), 3000);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Your state:</h1>
      {/* <h2>{a.props}</h2> // an erroneous return value */}
      <h2>{a !== null && a.props !== null ? a.props : "Loading ..."}</h2>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Working CodeSandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/stack-66736637-nullinreturn-6or9f